# How to know the index of dynamically created TabItem

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, tabcontrol, tabitem

I have in xaml like this:

```
<controls:TabControl Grid.Row="0" BorderThickness="0" Background="White" 
                         ItemsSource="{Binding TabList, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource TabConverter}}"                        
                         SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentItem, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

In viewmodel i have:

```
 private TabItem currentItem;
    public TabItem CurrentItem
    {
        get { return currentItem; }
        set 
        {
            //currentItem.Content               
            currentItem = value;
          int index = currentItem.TabIndex;  //IT GIVES STRANgE INDEX ON DEBUGGING ob Tab click (like 22255788586)                   
            OnPropertyChanged("CurrentItem");
        }
    }
```

But This TabList (in xaml) is generated dynamically like this:

```
public void AddVersion(ProgramVersion pv) //it creates the TabList
        {
            if (pv != null)
            {               
                if (index == -1)
                {                      
                    TabList.Add(new ProgramVersionItemViewModel(pv));                    
                    OnPropertyChanged("TabList");                
                }                
            }
        }
```

Each time press a button i call the function AddVersion(version); and it will added in TabList.

Problem is when i click to CurrentItem (of dynamically created number of TabItems (TabList)) then it gives strange address very big (like 222557456).

Is my way to get index of current item is wrong ? (int index = currentItem.TabIndex;) ?

Comment: `TabIndex` is *not* the index of the tab - it's there for ordering the controls while pressing TAB to cycle between controls.

Comment: **TabIndex** does NOT mean the item's index inside of the TabControl.Since you have a ViewModel List, the **SelectedItem** may not return the TabItem,it should refer to the ViewModel bound to the current TabItem.So you can try this **TabList.IndexOf(CurrentItem)** instead.

Comment: @Luaan so how to do the solution here to know index of the current item clicked Inside the Set of CurrentItem ?

Comment: @Claw Doing what you siad gives :  Error Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Windows.Controls.TabItem' to 'ViewModel.ProgramVersionItemViewModel'

Comment: It's not clear *why* you need the index. If you need to pass some information, you can use the `Tag` property instead, for example. Perhaps you could explain what you're actually trying to do?

Comment: @Luaan How can i pass the information using TagProperty  ? I tried "currentItem.Tag" and i want to get the information(pv) in currentItem invoke. I mean i would thank you if you tell me any way to access the "pv" Inside CurrentItem set()  ? (please note that this TabList contains the "pv") so if some how i know that which index is pressed then i can do something like this TabList[thatIndex].DataOfProgramVersionItemViewModelToAccess to acess that information.

Comment: You just set the `Tag` property to `pv`, and then when you want to read it, just do an explicit cast - `(ProgramVersion)currentItem.Tag`.

Answer (score 0):

7 years later and still no satisfying answer..

Here is a quick dummy fix, as long as you use `TabItem` instances to populate parent `TabControl` and don't mess with complex converters.

Put the code below inside an utility static (internal) class. Add the appropriate references like `using System.Windows.Controls` (or else directly create the static class under the `System.Windows.Controls` namespace)

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets the current index of the Tab under a TabControl.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="tabItem">This TabItem.</param>
/// <param name="defaultReturn">A default value to return if no index could be retrieved.</param>
/// <returns>The sequential index of the tab.</returns>
public static Int32 GetIndex(this TabItem tabItem, Int32 defaultReturn = 0) 
{
    if (tabItem == null) 
        throw new ArgumentNullException("tabItem", "TabItem is null.");
    if (tabItem.Parent is TabControl) 
    {
        TabControl parent = (TabControl)tabItem.Parent;
        int i = 0;

        foreach (var tab in parent.Items) 
        {
            if (ReferenceEquals(tab, tabItem)) 
                return i;

            i = i + 1;
        }
    }

    return defaultReturn;
}
```

Then you can use it :

```
// Select the latest created tab...
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => TheTabControl.SelectedIndex = CurrentItem.GetIndex(0)));
```

You can create other extensions methods on the same basis like TabControl.GetLastTab() or TabItem.SetIndex(0), but that's outside the scope of the topic.

Answer (score -1):

To be honest, that's one way of doing it. Here might be a better solution:

```
    private void Button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TabControl1.Items.Add(new TabItem() { TabIndex = 0, Header = "Tab 0" });
        TabControl1.Items.Add(new TabItem() { TabIndex = 1, Header = "Tab 1" });
        TabControl1.Items.Add(new TabItem() { TabIndex = 2, Header = "Tab 2" });
        TabControl1.Items.Add(new TabItem() { TabIndex = 3, Header = "Tab 3" });
    }
```

Notice that we are adding `new TabItem()` and providing it with its tab index and header. Using this approach is far more dynamic and far more reliable.

So, in your example, you might do something like this:

```
        if (pv != null)
        {
            if (index == -1)
            {
                TabList.Add(new TabItem() { TabIndex = <EnumeratedValue>, Header = "Tab " + <EnumeratedValue>.ToString()});
            }
        }
```

Comment: This is not a better solution if you are using an MVVM approach which the OP is likely using due to the way they are binding `CurrentItem`. Additionally, `TabIndex` isn't the index of the tab (as other commenters have already specified) but the order of the controls used when the user tabs through them. There is no index available on the tabs, the parent container has the index of the selected item (`SelectedIndex`) iirc.

Comment: Correct, and others are making that same comment as well. Although if you are dynamically adding and removing tabs, why not use the tabindex?  In the event the end user wishes to TAB through the tabs, your order will always be well defined.

Comment: Because WPF/SL automatically set the tab index based on the position of the controls on the page. You don't need to set it explicitly unless you are having serious issues or you want to set it to an order that isn't intuitive

Comment: Charleh - I didn't believe you at first, then I gave it a shot. I stand corrected.